# Dealing with information overload for rack mini profiler flamegraph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-mini-profiler, flamegraph

The flamegraph created by rack mini profiler has a lot of information, but I'm having difficulty dealing with it all, because of the large number of layers involved:

[image: Example screenshot]

Is it possible to hide the layers involving third-party gems, or display the information in text mode (akin to `--printer=graph` in ruby-prof)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way hiding layers, but I did a bit of a writeup on how to deal with the information overload here:

http://community.miniprofiler.com/t/how-to-deal-with-information-overload-in-flamegraphs/437?u=sam